# Find all tkinter fonts

Tags: python, tkinter

Where can I find a list of all the fonts that tkinter supports? I checked the source code of tkinter but I didn't find it. I see one(http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/colors.htm) that has all colors but I didn't find one for fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This outputs tkinter font names.

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter.font
Tk()
for name in sorted(tkinter.font.families()):
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this program that will print the font names on console if you enter it from the command line. it is python 2.7 but easy to change for 3.x. There is a little side effect that it opens a blank window - just ignore it. I have windows 10.

```
# show-tk-fonts.py
# Sunday, December 10, 2017      4:45:00 PM     -0600

import datetime
import sys
from   Tkinter import Tk
import tkFont

def mysort(a,b):
    if a[0] == '@':
        a = a[1:]
    if b[0] == '@':
        b = b[1:]
    return cmp(a.lower(), b.lower())

root = Tk()
print "# show-tk-fonts.py output"
print "#", datetime.datetime.now()
print
i    = 0
max  = 1
nam  = ""
fnames = list(tkFont.families())
fnames.sort(mysort)
for s in fnames:
    if len(s) > max:
        max = len(s)
        nam = s
    ls = 32-len(s)
    if i == 0:
        sys.stdout.write('    "'+s+'"'+' '*ls)
    else:
        sys.stdout.write('"'+s+'"'+' '*ls)
    i += 1
    if i == 3:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        i = 0
#print "max length = ",max
#print "name       = ",'"'+nam+'"'
print "normal exit"
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think you are answering my question...

Comment: What do you mean by "all" and "supports"; please clarify question.

Comment: Oh sorry you did answer my question. Your code seems a little bit complicated for my simple question.